# Passport.js not working, but registration is

Tags: javascript, passport.js

I'm trying to reinforce some concepts learned in Colt Steele's Web Development Bootcamp and I have built a small website. At this time, I'm just trying to get the authentication working properly.

When a user signs up, I can see that they are added to my Mongo DB so I'm assuming that is working correctly but when I try to log back in it always redirects to the error page.

I have tried debugging this a number of ways and have compared it to the work we did in the course a hundred times but I cannot spot the bug with this. If anyone could give me some guidance I would really appreciate it.

Here's my project repo:

https://github.com/mcarre93/Depa

Answer (score 0):

Ciao, according ti [passport docs](http://www.passportjs.org/docs/authenticate/), when you post `/login` you should do:

```
app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local'), function(req, res) {
     // If this function gets called, authentication was successful.
     // `req.user` contains the authenticated user.
     res.redirect('/account');
});
```

I read your code and you are doing something different. Try to modify your code as documentation suggest and let me know.

Comment: I tried doing this and it's still not working... now, instead of directing to the "Error" page it's just not loading. I'll comb through the documentation and see if I can find any other answers.